# Recursive build with QMake

Tags: qmake

I am (very) new to qmake, but i would like
to use qmake to build whole project automatically, 
so recursively check all subdirs and build every file.

I have a pch file too.

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: Are you trying to build one thing (application or library) made up of multiple files in subdirs, or are you trying to build multiple multiple libraries and apps spread out in multiple subdirs?

Comment: I am trying to build one library made up of multiple files.
At this time, by typing all subdirs manually, it can be compiled, but
I get "undefined reference" errors at using that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to let qmake generate the qmake file for you.

After making a backup copy of any exist *.pro files you may need to reference, go to the top level of your directory structure and issue the command `qmake -project`.  This tells qmake to recurse the tree and locate everything it needs to build and create a qmake project file from it.

Next, edit the generated qmake file.  You will at least need to change the TEMPLATE line to be "lib" instead of "app".  You will also want to specify the name of the TARGET.  There may also be some other things you wish to change.

Now that you have a qmake file, you need to generate a make file.  Run qmake again, but this time just say `qmake` without any arguments.

Finally, you should be able to just run `make` and have things build.   [For future readers running Windows with the MingW tools, `make` should be replaced with `mingw32-make`]